# Uploading multiple images using PHP

Tags: php, security, image, network-file-transfer

I literally spend all day working on PHP and I think I figured it out, but I need some reviews in order to make my code secure & okay. I am asking you about functionality here. The code below works.

#### index.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="file_container">
        <input name="images[]" multiple type="file" id="file[]"/><br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

#### upload.php

```
$target = "upload/";

$uploadit = 1; // I will change it with extension checker.
$checksize = // will check file size

foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value){
    $path = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $name = md5($name);
    $generate1 = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
    $randomizer = uniqid($name);
    $name = $name . $generate1 . $randomizer;
        if ($uploadit == 1) {
               if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $target.$name.".".$ext)){
                echo "<strong>".$value ."</strong>Your files have been upload successfully<br />\n";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Failed";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$target` is accessible from a web browser, you need to verify that it does not have a dangerous extension.  For example, that it's not a PHP file.  Note that there are probably other dangerous extensions on your web server other than just '*.php*'.  For example, '*.html*' is a dangerous extension because of cross-site scripting type vulnerabilities.

You include a flag variable for this, but you aren't doing the checking.

```
$uploadit = 1; // I will change it with extension checker.
```

Why not use a Boolean here?

```
$uploadit = false; // I will change it with extension checker.
```

Also, it probably makes more sense to default to no and change to yes than to default to yes.

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value){
    $path = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Could just be

```
foreach ( $_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $path ) {
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

In general, prefer more descriptive names than `$key => $value`.  In this case, I believe that `$key` is a numeric index, so `$i` or `$index` might be more appropriate.

```
$name = md5($name);
```

What's `$name`?

```
    if ($uploadit == 1) {
```

Given PHP's quirkiness, this should probably be

```
    if ( true === $uploadit ) {
```

According to the [PHP date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php),

```
$generate1 = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
```

The `date()` function will always return '000000' for microseconds (u).

```
$date = new DateTime();
$generate1 = md5($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
```

Use `DateTime::format()` instead.

```
$randomizer = uniqid($name);
```

This does nothing for security.  Its purpose is to avoid clashes.  Note that this will put `$name` in the name twice.

```
$randomizer = $name . uniqid();
```

This does the same thing as the previous statement.

```
$name = $name . $generate1 . $randomizer;
```

You can write

```
$name .= $generate1 . $randomizer;
```

Not important now, but the next time you hit this situation, you might want to go with the shorter version.

Note that it is safer to put `$target` outside the web accessible area.  If you do that, then it is less of a concern about the extension.  If you do not do that, then you should care about the extension even if the filename is hard to guess.  It's not clear to me why you need it in a web accessible area if you are going to obfuscate the name.

Obfuscating the name does not provide security.  There have been exploits that have allowed attackers to view directory contents.  Also, there are any number of existing users that can do that.  Finally, you can't use the image without sharing the obfuscated name--possibly with an attacker.  So you might as well use the original name and secure that.

If you are trying to avoid name clashes, you might be better off with a database solution.  An autoincrement identifier with a unique index will be consistently unique and kept that way by the database.

It is preferable to whitelist extensions rather than blacklist them.  That way a change in the web server configuration can't open up a new dangerous extension when you aren't looking.

There's things you can do in either .htaccess or httpd configuration to prevent files in `$target` being evaluated in scripts.  For example, [disable CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18932756/2625983).  You should probably do something like this in *addition* to an extension whitelist.